# Depth first algorithm using an adjacency matrix not working properly

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I tried to do a depth first algorithm. And this is what I have so far.

```
void DepthFirst(int A[][100], int a, int visited[], int nNodes)
{
// Here I'm supposed to list all the nodes in the graph, starting with 'a'

// Mark 'a' visited (1)
visited[a] = 1;
// Write a
cout << char(a + 'a') << " , ";
// For each node n adjacent to 'a' do
for (int n = 0; n < nNodes; n++)
{
    if (A[a][n] = 1)
    {// If n is not visited, then
        if (visited[n] == 0)
        {
            DepthFirst(A, n, visited, nNodes);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following graph to test it:

[image: Graph]

which has the following adjacency table:

[image]

Using that table I wrote my main function:

```
int main()
{
int a = 0;
int v[100] = { 0 };
int nNodes = 8;

int A[][100] =
{
    { 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0 },
    { 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    { 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1 },
    { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1 },
    { 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0 },
};
DepthFirst(A, a, v, nNodes);
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

And it isn't working. The output should be

```
a,b,c,d,f,g,e,h,i,k,j,
```

Instead, I get

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

Can someone help me fix it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. The first one is easy to find if you ask the compiler nicely enough. `g++` with `-Wall` [tells you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3702a68d24b2c8d0) the first mistake right away - in `DepthFirst`, you wrote `if (A[a][n] = 1)` when you meant `if (A[a][n] == 1)`. The next mistake is `int nNodes = 8;` in `main`. You have a graph with `11` nodes. Fix them both and [profit](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13a09da4eb31cc58)!